# My database don't show any values just 0

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio-2012, xampp

I have my database XAMPP MySQL and I put values from Visual Studio 2012.

I have the code for `INSERT INTO` mytable, but I always insert the value, this value appears like 0.
I don't know the reason because if I'm connected to the Database and I send the value, the table normally show the value I write.
Someone knows the problem???

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports MySql.Data
Imports System.Data

Public Class Form1
    Dim Posto_1 As Integer
    Dim Posto_2 As Integer
    Dim Posto_3 As Integer
    Dim Posto_4 As Integer
    Dim Ip_Address As Integer

    Dim myConnectionString As String = "SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=base_de_dados; UID=root; PASSWORD=123;"

    Private Sub inserir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles inserir.Click
        Dim insert_bd As String = "INSERT INTO linha(endereco_ip, t_paragem_1, t_paragem_2, t_paragem_3, t_paragem_4) VALUES ('@endereco_ip', '@t_paragem_1', '@t_paragem_2', '@t_paragem_3', '@t_paragem_4');"
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(myConnectionString)
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand(insert_bd, connection)

        If (posto1Text.Text = "" Or posto2Text.Text = "" Or posto3Text.Text = "" Or posto4Text.Text = "" Or ipText.Text = "") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Não foi inserido nenhum valor")
        Else
            Ip_Address = CInt(ipText.Text)
            Posto_1 = CInt(posto1Text.Text)
            Posto_2 = CInt(posto2Text.Text)
            Posto_3 = CInt(posto3Text.Text)
            Posto_4 = CInt(posto4Text.Text)

            Try
                connection.Open()
                ListBox1.Items.Add("Base de Dados --> Escrever. . .")
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endereco_ip", Ip_Address)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t_paragem_1", Posto_1)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t_paragem_2", Posto_2)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t_paragem_3", Posto_3)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t_paragem_4", Posto_4)
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Erro de ligação", "AVISO!!!")
            End Try

            connection.Close()
            connection = Nothing
            command = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked return codes from the SQL calls?  Have you tried the same query using PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: The problem its ('@endereco_ip', '@t_paragem_1', '@t_paragem_2', '@t_paragem_3', '@t_paragem_4').

Comment: I nedd to put of the  ', and work